# How to calculate the number of days between dates picked on a date picker calender

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying to calculate the number of days between the dates selected on a date picker and use that value to calculate for the **`totalPrice`** value in the database.

```
db.define_table('invoice',
    Field('loaning_date', 'date', label=SPAN('Date Loaned', _style="font-weight: bold;"), requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('returning_date', 'date', label=SPAN('Date Returned', _style="font-weight: bold;"), requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                              #Number of days calculation
    Field('daysLoaned', compute=lambda r: (r['returning_date']-r['loaning_date']).days),
    Field('price', 'float', label=SPAN('Price', _style="font-weight: bold;"), requires=IS_MATCH('[0-9]+', error_message=T('Enter Money in Proper Figures'))),
    Field('totalPrice', compute=lambda r: float(r['price'])* int(r['daysLoaned']), label=SPAN('Total Price', _style="font-weight: bold;")))
```

I expect this line below
**`Field('daysLoaned', compute=lambda r: (r['returning_date']-r['loaning_date']).days)`** 
to give me an integer value depending on the selected dates. But instead i'm getting this error
 
**`<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`**
I don't know what I'm doing wrong where!

Comment: The error is explanatory, it says the - (minus) operator doesn't work between 'str' and 'str'. That means the value of r['returning_date'] is a string. Python won't magically understand that the string is a date and perform subtraction. It would be helpful if you could do a print(r['returning_date']) and tell us the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your traceback says, your dates are in string format and you can't use the subtraction operand with strings. An option is to import datetime and use strptime to convert the string to datetime objects and then use the subtraction operand to get the difference.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime

returning_date = datetime.strptime("2019/1/1 0:30", '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
loaning_date = datetime.strptime("2019/1/10 0:30", '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
diff = returning_date - loaning_date
print(diff)
>>> -9 days, 0:00:00
```

You can access just the days by:

```
print(diff.days)
>>> -9
```

Which have type:

```
print(type(diff.days))
>>> <class 'int'>
```

In your code this would look something like this (depending on how your string is formatted):

```
(datetime.strptime(r['returning_date'], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M') - datetime.strptime(r['loaning_date'], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')).days
```

Comment: The thing is i had used the same formula ```Field('daysLoaned', compute=lambda r: (r['returning_date']-r['loaning_date']).days),```previously in another application & it worked, it surprised me this time around when it generated an error. The above solution from @Anna Nevison solved my problem.